# Programmatically remove duplicated nodes without changing the number of nodes shown per page

Tags: 8, views

I have a content type called *Página de área* (*Area page*) referenced by two content type: *Article* and *Agrupador*. I have a view that displays all the *Article* nodes that share at least one area with an *Agrupador* node.

My goal is removing the duplicate nodes (I get calling `$query->addWhere()`) from the view.
I already tried using the *Distinct* and *Aggregation* options in the user interface, but they didn't work for me. I'm aware that this can be achieved using `hook_views_pre_render()`, but if (for example) I have 10 nodes per page and two nodes are duplicates, the view ends up showing eight nodes instead of 10.

I also tried what shown in [Update view result and pager in hook_views_pre_render()](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-10-10/update-view-result-and-pager-in-hook_views_pre_render) and in [Distinct doesn't work when sorting by field with multiple values](https://www.drupal.org/node/1223448#comment-4757898) using the following code.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function gcaba_agrupador_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, Sql $query) {
  if ($view->id() == 'noticias_agrupador' && $view->current_display == 'noticias_agrupador') {
    $agrupador = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($agrupador instanceof NodeInterface) {
      $agrupador = Node::load($agrupador->id());
      $areas = explode(',', $agrupador->field_area->getString());
      $areasArray = array_map('intval', $areas);
      $query->addWhere(0, 'node__field_area.field_area_target_id', $areasArray, 'IN');
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: What does *affecting the pager functionality* exactly mean? If a view is altered to show less nodes, the pager should be updated to still show the number of pages required to show all the nodes.

Comment: The question explains that `hook_views_pre_render()` would break the pager, but then shows an implementation of `hook_views_query_alter()` and it does not say what is wrong with that implementation.

Comment: (Those are probably the details missing in the question, for which the question has been voted to be closed.)

Comment: You didn't include what Aggregation settings you tried. It can be be done with Aggregation but you have to know what you're doing, it doesn't happen by simply enabling it. You have to find which field should be changed to "Entity ID" from "Value" or something like that. You should also make that happen (remove duplicates) without any Sorting and maybe even Pagination, and only bring them back once you're able to aggregate duplicates into single rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 *
 * @param \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view
 * @param \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase $query
 */
function gcaba_agrupador_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->id() == 'noticias_agrupador' && $view->current_display == 'noticias_agrupador') {
    $agrupador = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($agrupador instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $agrupador = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($agrupador->id());
      $areas = explode(',', $agrupador->field_area->getString());
      $areasArray = array_map('intval', $areas);
      
      $query->addWhere(0, 'node__field_area.field_area_target_id', $areasArray, 'IN');

      // Remove duplicates using DISTINCT.
      $query->distinct();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work :( The pager is not  updated with deleted nodes.

Comment: lets try a diffrent approach. I just updated the code by keeping the query alter and adding the distinct attribute. Try it and let me know

Comment: It was a good shot. But distinct method is undefined

Comment: [`QueryPluginBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21query%21QueryPluginBase.php/class/QueryPluginBase/9) shows all the available methods, but `distinct()` is not one of them.